# What does the "L" mean at the end of an integer literal?

Tags: c++

I have this constant:

```
#define MAX_DATE  2958465L
```

What does the L mean in this sense?

Comment: It's not a constant but a macro (that expands to a literal).

Comment: so what does the number expand to then?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is a `long` integer literal.

Integer literals have a type of `int` by default; the `L` suffix gives it a type of `long`  (Note that if the value cannot be represented by an `int`, then the literal will have a type of `long` even without the suffix).

Comment: Sure? AFAIK literals without the 'L' suffix are of integer type in C++, and it will fail to compile if the literal will not fit in the int type.

Comment: @David:  "If it is decimal and has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `long  int` (C++03 §2.13.1/2).

Comment: So it seems like compiler can choose for us automatically. When do we want to put in the `L` suffix ourselves?

Comment: @kizzx2:  `42` is an `int`.  If you want it to be a `long`, you need to add the `L` (giving `42L`).  There are many reasons that you might want a `long` explicitly:  you might do it to select a particular function overload or to ensure a template is instantiated with `long` instead of `int`.  You might use it to ensure some integer expression is evaluated with `long` precision instead of `int` precision.  `INT_MAX + 1` will overflow.  If `long` has greater range than `int`, `INT_MAX + 1L` will not overflow.

Answer (score 9):

In this scenario the `L`does nothing.

The `L` after a number gives the constant the `long` type, but because in this scenario the constant is immediately assigned to an `int` variable nothing is changed.

Comment: Could you give an example where it does do something?

Comment: @Celeritas This is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134956/what-is-the-reason-for-explicitly-declaring-l-or-ul-for-long-values

Answer (score 4):

L tells the compiler that the number is of type Long.  Long is a signed type greater than or equal to an int in size.  On most modern compilers, this means that the number will take 4 bytes of memory.  This happens to be the same as an int on most compilers so it won't have an effect in this case.

Comment: long is signed, on mac os, using gcc, long is 8 byte long.

Answer (score 1):

see [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20130807052041/http://cpp.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html) link
it says :

Literal constants (often referred to as literals or constants) are invariants whose values are implied by their representations.

base:decimal

example:1L

description:
Any decimal number (digits 0-9) not beginning with a 0 (zero) and followed by L or l