# Implicit declaration of function x

Tags: c, algorithm, prime-factoring

I'm well aware of function prototypes, this error seems to be a function declaration error, which means I'm really bewildered as to why I'm see this warning and thus error.

It's almost like gcc completely ignores my function prototype. Is this a compiler bug?

In the interest of brevity, I did not declare this function in a separate header file, though it should make no difference.

gcc output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic primefactors.c
primefactors.c: In function ‘main’:
primefactors.c:8:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘largestprime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
primefactors.c: At top level:
primefactors.c:12:6: error: conflicting types for ‘largestprime’
primefactors.c:8:20: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘largestprime’ was here
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long largetsprime(long);

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", largestprime(600851475143));
    return 0;
}

long largestprime(long num)
{
    int highest;
    int mid = sqrt(num);
    for (int i = 2; i < mid; i++) {
        if (mid % i == 0) {
            if (i % 1 == 0 && i % i == 0)
                highest = i;
        }
    }
    return highest;
}
```

Comment: A comment would be nice in regards to the downvote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Point-1**
You have misspelled `largest` in function name

```
long largetsprime(long)
           ^
           s is wrong here
```

In declaration It should be

```
long largestprime(long)
          ^ before t
```

**Point-2**
You are using `sqrt()` library function from `math.h`, you should compile your program with `-lm` as:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic primefactors.c -lm
```

**Point-3**
You are returning `int` whereas return type of your function is `long`.

**Point-4**
One more <del>mistake</del> suggestion in call of `printf()` you forgot adding suffix for `long int`.

```
largestprime(600851475143)
```

should be:

```
largestprime(600851475143L)
      //                 ^ added  suffix  L for long
```

If you are not aware of suffix `L` then read: [What does the “L” mean at the end of an integer literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958007/what-does-the-l-mean-at-the-end-of-an-integer-literal)

Thanks to @[Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil):

**point-5:** `printf()` in `main()` function is printing `long` type integer whereas you have used `%d` format specifier to print it:

```
printf("%d\n", largestprime(600851475143));
                 ^
                 | 
                 returns long
```

use `%ld` instead.

**point-6:**

`if`-condition in largest prime function  `i % 1 == 0 and i % i == 0` are each always true (except the latter is undefined if `i` is zero) because `i % 1` = `0` (every number is divisible by `1`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been refactoring this code for the last few hours to solve this project euler problem; it's probably not my best code.

Comment: @TheBlueCat No problem BlueCat! I just wanted to share what I encountered hence added. You Welcome!

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the literals in C. Thank you, though. I guess it's useful anyway.

Comment: The `L` suffix on the constant is unnecessary. The constant will be an integer type sufficient to represent the value, and it will converted to `long` for passing to the function. A bigger concern is that the format specifier is `%d`, which is for `int`, but the value passed for it has type `long`. Additionally `i % 1 == 0` and `i % i == 0` are each always true (except the latter is undefined if `i` is zero).

Comment: @EricPostpischil get it! Understood first message as well as second. Eric You should be a teacher! :) Thanks .. your comments are very helpful (not only for answering, but also for me)  I'm learning from you new things.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Nice! good pics can I add in my answer these points

Comment: As I said it's extremely rushed code. I had a batter version that did not work, so I didn't post it.

Comment: @TheBlueCat no problem man! I am happy that I got a nice badge for what I am looking for. Thanks mat!

Answer (score 2):

Typo. The declaration says `largeTSprime`. Change it to the correct `largestprime` and it will work.

ProTip #1: use `camelCapsOnWordBoundaries` or `under_scores` for readability.

ProTip #2: it's almost **never a compiler bug.**

Comment: well, 99.99% of the time.

Comment: @TheBlueCat Noticed 'almost'?

Comment: I wanted to quantify it more; gcc is pretty stable, especially on stable distros.

Comment: @TheBlueCat Ah, OK; misinterpreter that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the prototype. It should be `largestprime` instead of `largetsprime`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the prototype:

```
largetsprime != largestprime
```