# C shifting (char shifting)!

Tags: c

I need some help in understanding this code of C. I don't know what "L" and "\" is here?
Please illustrate a little bit too :)

```
#define l2n(l,c)        (*((c)++)=(unsigned char)(((l)>>24L)&0xff), \
                         *((c)++)=(unsigned char)(((l)>>16L)&0xff), \
                         *((c)++)=(unsigned char)(((l)>> 8L)&0xff), \
                         *((c)++)=(unsigned char)(((l)     )&0xff))
```

All help is welcome :)

Comment: L means long. \ escapes ending the macro.

Comment: l is the first parameter of your macro.

Comment: It's just a macro which writes a 4 byte value (`l`) to the buffer pointed at by `c`, in *big endian* order (i.e. most significant byte first). The `c` pointer is also incremented by 4 bytes.

Comment: Where is this code from? It seems to try triggering conversion to at least `long` if `l` has a smaller rank, which isn't possible like that in ISO C (but was possible in K&R C iirc, so it might be old code.)

Comment: The `L` in `24L` makes 24 a `long` rather than `int` constant.  It serve no purpose to use it here as it does not affect the type of the result.  This is a poor macro.

Comment: @chux: Yes, but where does it make any difference in the code shown?

Comment: @mafso It makes no difference.  Suspect the author thought it would insure that `l` is converted to `long`, but it does not do that.

Comment: @chux, yes, this was my thought as well. Afair, this really worked in K&R (`1 << 1L` was of type `long` like `1 + 1L` is in ISO C), which is why I asked where the code is from...

Comment: @harper I am not clear about your comment.  What does `L` have to do with any including or omitting any casts?

Comment: [What does the "L" mean at the end of an integer literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958007/what-does-the-l-mean-at-the-end-of-an-integer-literal)

Comment: @Lu'u The L indicates the preceeding number as a LONG value. Since you can't shift much more thsn 64 bit positions the L is superflous here.

Answer (score 1):

This illustrates how a big-endian value is written on my little-endian machine. More explanation: the `&0xff` part masks off all except the least signifcant 8 bits of the shifted value, although as I am unsure whether that or the `(unsigned char)` are strictly necessary, I included a macro `n2n()` without them as a comparison. Without them, I get no compiler warning and no error.

Also I have omitted the `L` discussed in comments above. Note too that the pointer used must be an `unsigned char` type - if it was an `unsigned int` type, `c` would be incremented by 4 (32-bit architecture). That's why I have used a `union` to overlay the bytes.

The macro definition must have no space between its identifier and the first bracket. And finally if there seem to be more brackets than necessary in the macros, it is to ensure that any expression is correctly compiled, for example `l2n(a+b,c);`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define l2n(l,c) (*((c)++)=(unsigned char)(((l)>>24)&0xff), \
                  *((c)++)=(unsigned char)(((l)>>16)&0xff), \
                  *((c)++)=(unsigned char)(((l)>> 8)&0xff), \
                  *((c)++)=(unsigned char)(((l)    )&0xff))

#define n2n(l,c) (*((c)++)=(l)>>24, \
                  *((c)++)=(l)>>16, \
                  *((c)++)=(l)>> 8, \
                  *((c)++)=(l)    )
typedef union {
    unsigned num;
    unsigned char arr[4];
    } bigend;

int main (void)
{
    bigend number;
    unsigned x;
    char *p;

    // test first macro
    x = 0x12345678;
    p = number.arr;
    printf ("Input  %08X\n", x);
    l2n(x,p);
    printf ("Output %08X\n\n", number.num);

    // test second macro
    x = 0x89ABCDEF;
    p = number.arr;
    printf ("Input  %08X\n", x);
    n2n(x,p);
    printf ("Output %08X\n\n", number.num);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Input  12345678
Output 78563412

Input  89ABCDEF
Output EFCDAB89
```